# Visualizing a time series data to compare the scores of groups based on each day of participation

Tags: time-series, data-visualization, ggplot2, interactive-visualization, matplotlib

I have the following data but not sure about the best way to visualize it.

Average assignment scores for the users starting to participate in the first, second, third, and so on, days of the course.

```
                    Assign1 | Assign2 | Assign3 | Assign4 | Assign5 | Assign6
day-1-participants  15      | 20      | 8       | 12      | 15      | 22
day-2-participants  13      | 17      | 9       | 14      | 15      | 21
.
.
day 90-participants 5       | 7       | 12      | 0       | 0       | 0
```

And similarly I have the **percentage** of users from each day who completed the assignment:

```
                    Assign1 | Assign2 | Assign3 | Assign4 | Assign5 | Assign6
day-1-participants  90      | 88      | 84      | 75      | 69      | 63
day-2-participants  88      | 87      | 83      | 74      | 67      | 60
.
.
day 90-participants 10      | 7       | 5       | 0       | 0       | 0
```

I wonder what would be an effective way of visualizing this data to show that late comers generally performs worse in the assignments. To the degree they are late, their performance gets worse (especially toward the latest assignments) and their participation rate decreases significantly.

I wonder if you guys have any suggestions? I can use the table as I posted here, but normally have around 200 days, and reading such a large table and making inferences would be very hard. I am comfortable using any visualization tool (but mostly a python library).

Thanks!

Comment: You could plot each matrix as an image using imshow() such as explained in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784354/imshow-when-you-are-plotting-data-not-images-realtion-between-aspect-and-exten Yet i wonder, how do you identify late comers? In both matrices, there is only aggregated information about all students.

Comment: @NikolasRieble Thanks! as the days get closer to 90, the uses are more like late comers, and for example for the 90th day, I only consider students who first starting participated on that day (the same for all days)

Comment: So for each day, you only evaluate those, which arrived late? Are the assignments the same on every day? If so, plotting an image will most likely visualize what you want. Please provide feedback, whether it was a good idea - since i am curious as well. :)

Comment: Assignments are on different days. Actually, I was also considering to try the latest plot here https://plot.ly/python/heatmaps/. It kinda make sense. I will keep you updated!